# AFNetworking and setting up request queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm making a AFRequestionOperation call:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Other code

        AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] init];
        [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFImageRequestOperation class]];
        [client.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];

        self.HTTPClient = client;
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I need to make the request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *request = [self.HTTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Code
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Code
}];

[self.HTTPClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:request];
```

When I check the queue:

```
DLog(@"queue: %@", self.HTTPClient.operationQueue);
```

it shows the queue as `null`.

it doesn't make any calls.

I can use:

```
[request start];
```

but pretty sure that isn't use the Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the designated initializer of `AFHTTPClient`:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Comment: Yep, just started digging thru `AFHTTPClient` and saw that. There is no overridden `init` method. =/ Thanks for pointing that out.